# Add a method to array object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I've found this post:

[Array#add_condition](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5147)
But i didn't understand to how implement it in my rails project

How can i do it?

thanks

Comment: I don't think it's a great design. You're adding very specific functionality for building a WHERE clause to the general purpose Array class. It might be better to do this in the model base class, or perhaps by adding something to ActiveRecord::Base.

Answer (score 1):

Just create `add_condition.rb` file, paste code snippet from your link and save it in `lib` directory in your Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste that code into a file. There — the method is added to Array. The `lib` directory would be a good place for it.